# Don't trigger onClick for nested child elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, click

I have a simple modal component:

```
function Modal(props) {
  return (
    <div className={cx(styles.overlay, { show: props.show })} onClick={props.onClose}>
      <div className={styles.modal}>
        <span className={styles.closeBtn} onClick={props.onClose} />
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

the onClose prop triggers closing the modal, hence I attach it to `styles.overlay` (dark overlay that you typically see on modals that when clicked dissmises it) and to `styles.closeBtn` (a close button for modal).

The whole flow works besides the fact that anything inside `styles.overlay` when clicked on also dismisses the modal, which is not functionality I was after, hence I need to only dismiss it if that specific element is clicked not its children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Modal(props) {
   return (
     <div className={cx(styles.overlay, { show: props.show })} onClick= {props.onClose}>
       <div className={styles.modal} onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>
         <span className={styles.closeBtn} onClick={props.onClose} />
         {props.children}
       </div>
   </div>
   )
}
```

I think, the best way is to have your overlay and your modal in two separate div, but this should work.

Comment: Nice-- our solutions are similar.

Answer (score 0):

Add `onClick(e)={e.stopPropagation();}` to the modal dialog's click handler; this should prevent it from propagating to the overlay.

Hope it works! Good luck!